# There exist infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am working on the following exercsie:

> If $p$ divides $2^{2^n}+1$, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{n+1}}$. Conclude that for all $n \ge 2$ exist infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$.

I have shown that $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{n+1}}$. But I do not get how I should show that ther are "infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$". Could you help me?

Comment: Hint:  show that distinct Fermat numbers are relatively prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking lulu's advice, you can merely show the Fermat numbers (numbers of the form $2^{2^n}+1$) are mutually coprime.

Let $n\neq m$.  Without loss of generality, we can assume $n>m$.  We wish to show $\gcd(2^{2^n}+1, 2^{2^m}+1)=1$.  Notice that by factoring with difference of squares, we have

$$2^{2^n}-1=(2^{2^0}-1)(2^{2^0}+1)(2^{2^1}+1)(2^{2^2}+1)\ldots(2^{2^{n-1}}+1)$$

and thus, $2^{2^m}+1|2^{2^n}-1$.  In particular, we have $\gcd(2^{2^n}+1, 2^{2^m}+1)\leq \gcd(2^{2^n}+1, 2^{2^n}-1)=\gcd(2^{2^n}-1, 2)=1$, so Fermat numbers are coprime.

Given that they are coprime, if $p_n$ is a prime divisor of $2^{2^n}+1$ for each $n$, then all these primes must be distinct.  Therefore, the sequence ${p_n}$ must contain infinitely many primes.  By your observation, $p_n \equiv 1 \mod 2^{n+1}$, and so in particular, $p_n \equiv 1 \mod 2^k$ for all $k$, $1\leq k \leq n+1$.  The claim follows.