# Primes equivalent to 1 (mod 8) Proof

Tags: prime-numbers

Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to $1 \pmod{8}.$

I've tried using proof by contradiction:

- if there are only $n$ primes equivalent to $1 \pmod{8}$ with a product of $P$, then $(2P)^4 + 1 \equiv 1\pmod8.$

How do I finish this off?

Comment: Do you know how to show that a prime divisor of a number of that form must be $1 \bmod 8$?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399694/show-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-that-are-equivalent-to-1-mod-8) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to 1 mod 8.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399694/show-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-that-are-equivalent-to-1-mod-8)

Comment: @RobertMugabe FYI, another solution method involves a quite different approach using the factors of [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number), such as shown at [There exist infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3403589/602049).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one line answer would be to use Dirichlet's theorem for primes in arithmetic progression (Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). The statement of this theorem says that if $a$ and $b$ are integers with $gcd$ 1, then there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression $\{a+bn:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. In your question $a=1$ and $b=8$ which are coprime. So this theorem gives your result. But this is like killing an ant with a tank!

Your proof can be completed by showing that the only prime divisors of $M=(2P)^4+1$ are of the form $8k+1.$ The proof to this fact is given in [Prove that if $p$ is an odd prime that divides a number of the form $n^4 + 1$ then $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33392/prove-that-if-p-is-an-odd-prime-that-divides-a-number-of-the-form-n4-1-th). Now suppose $p$ is an odd prime dividing $M$ ($2\nmid M$ as $M$ is odd) then $p\equiv 1(\bmod 8).$ But since there are only $n$ such primes by hypothesis, it must be one out of these $n$ many primes. But if
$$
M=(2P)^4+1\equiv 0(\bmod p)\\
\implies (2P)^4\equiv -1(\bmod p)
$$
which is a contradiction since $P\equiv 0(\bmod p).$ Thus there are no divisors of $M$ and hence $M$ is a prime with $M\equiv 1(\bmod 8)$ which contradicts the fact that there are only $n$ such primes. Thus there must be infinitely many such primes.

Note: This type of "Euclidean elementary proof" can be given only for specific cases. Ram murty has discussed in [https://mast.queensu.ca/~murty/murty-thain2.pdf](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/murty-thain2.pdf) the extent to which Euclidean proof can be given.